# Edited Access control exercise - java

Tags: java, class, encapsulation

I need to print the attributes from `TestCar` class by creating a `public hackCar` method in class `Terminal`. The `hackCar` method needs to take a `TestCar` as a parameter and print the attributes of `TestCar`. The caveat for this assignment is that I cannot touch anything in the `TestCar` class.

I am still struggling with printing the two `private` attributes in `TestCar`. How can I print the two `private` attributes from `TestCar` class by using the `TestCar` object as the parameter in the `hackCar` method?

Story class:

```
class Story {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestCar testCar = new TestCar();
        Terminal terminal = new Terminal();
        terminal.hackCar(testCar);
    }
}

class Terminal {

    public void hackCar(TestCar other) {

        System.out.println(other.doorUnlockCode);

        System.out.println(other.hasAirCondition);

        System.out.println(other.brand);

        System.out.println(other.licensePlate);
    }
}

class TestCar {

    private int doorUnlockCode = 602413;
    protected boolean hasAirCondition = false;
    String brand = "TurboCarCompany";
    public String licensePlate = "PHP-600";
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you can't touch the class TestCar, you can't set any Getter methods to access the private members of the class from outside the class.

So, the only way to do it (access the Private members of the class without using any Getter Functions), is to use the Reflection API in java.

Here is the code,

```
public void hackCar(TestCar other) {

        Field f = other.getDeclaredField("doorUnlockCode");  /*here we create the object of the desired field*/

        f.setAccessible(true);  //here, we set its access to true

        System.out.println(f.get(obj));   /*here, we use the field object to get its value*/

        Field f1 = other.getDeclaredField("hasAirCondition");

        f1.setAccessible(true);

        System.out.println(f1.get(obj));

        Field f2 = other.getDeclaredField("brand");

        f2.setAccessible(true);

        System.out.println(f2.get(obj));

        System.out.println(other.licensePlate);  /*this can be accessed directly since the access specifier for the field is "public"*/
    }
```

You can modify your HackCar method this way.

You will need to import these.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
```

This is a solution to the above problem, but it has its own flaws. It causes **Performance Overheads** and also causes **Security Problems** as it violates the **Abstraction** principle of **OOP**.

So, use this solution judiciously.

NOTE - You can also access the fields that have their access specifiers **protected** or **default**, by defining a class (let's call it C) in the same package as the TestCar class, and using the member functions of the class C as the getter functions for the **protected** and **default** fields of the TestCar class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the private properties of an object outside of the class. That's what `Encapsulation` is all about in `OOP`. If the properties of a class must be accessible from outside of the class, they can't be private. Or you should provide some accessor methods for them. I think that's why `Java Beans` are so popular in java frameworks.

Also you can use `Reflection` to access private properties of a class in java, but i don't think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioning three classes: `Story`, `Terminal`, `TestCar`. All of them are defined package private (default visibility) in your question - maybe for the sake of simplicity. But either `TestCar` is defined `public` and/or `Story` / `Terminal` reside in the same package. Only then `TestCar` can be resolved within `Story` and `Terminal`.

If the classes are all within one package then it is possible to immediately access the fields `hasAirCondition`, `brand` and `licensePlate` of `TestCar` in `Terminal.hackCar(...)`. Thus this access is possible without reflections.

If `TestCar` is defined `public` and in package `lib.cars` but `Story` and `Terminal` are in your project's package `app.cars` then a class `Accessor` defined in your project in package `lib.cars` can provide access to the package visible fields `hasAirCondition` and `brand`:

```
package lib.cars;

public class Accessor {

  public static boolean hasAirCondition(TestCar testCar) {
    return testCar.hasAirCondition;
  }

  public static String getBrand(TestCar testCar) {
    return testCar.brand;
  }

}
```

Thus you can still access three of four fields of `TestCar`.

The `private` field will remain always inaccessible without reflections. Since the other answers are explaining how to access the fields of `TestCar` using reflections I will not repeat it. My answer is therefore a complement to the other answers.

But as stated in the other answers, using reflections has it's drawbacks - i.e. refactorings like a simple renaming of the field `doorUnlockCode` to `doorsUnlockCode`. So maybe one should go the regular way as long as possible and use reflection as a last resort.

We could incorporate both ways in the `Accessor` class:

```
package lib.cars;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Accessor {

  public static boolean hasAirCondition(TestCar testCar) {
    return testCar.hasAirCondition;
  }

  public static String getBrand(TestCar testCar) {
    return testCar.brand;
  }

  public static int getDoorUnlockCode(TestCar testCar) throws Exception {
    Field field = TestCar.class.getDeclaredField("doorUnlockCode");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return (int) field.get(testCar);
  }

}
```

Using it in `Terminal` as follows:

```
public class Terminal {

  public void hackCar(TestCar other) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(Accessor.getDoorUnlockCode(other));

    System.out.println(Accessor.hasAirCondition(other));

    System.out.println(Accessor.getBrand(other));

    System.out.println(other.licensePlate);
  }

}
```